# pine-script function returns different value than expected

Tags: pine-script

I am struggling with the understanding of function executions in pine-script. Please see the short script below, it should compile as it is:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
a = 100.
d = 100.

d:=nz(d[1]) + 10

f_(_src) => nz(_src[1]) + 10
a := f_(a)

plot(a, "a", color.red, 5)
plot(d, "d", color.yellow, 5)
```

I would expect, that the value of  `a` and `d` are the same, as the function "f_" executes the same code as in the assignment for `d`. 
But `a` has always a constant value of 110 from the 2nd cycle, when `d` increases each cycle linearly +10.

What is the reason it behaves like this? I would be very happy about some reference.

Thank you a lot for your help, Seb.

[image: a != d, d's value increases linear, a stay constant]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables are initialized to `100.` on every bar.

For variable `a`:

- The value passed to `f_()` is always the `a` variable which has just been initialized to `100.`, as it's initialized on every bar, but once inside the function, that current value isn't used. Because you use `nz(_src[1])`, the value used is the value of the parameter the last time the function was called, all this from the function's perspective—not the global scope's perpective.
- On the function's first call, the `nz()` call replaces the value with `0` as there is no previous value. The function returns `10`.
- On the second bar and all subsequent ones, you are still calling the function with the `a=100` argument, but from thereon a previous value exists for the argument inside the function. It is always `100.` because that's what you are calling the function with every time, so `nz(_src[1])` always returns `100.`, and the function always returns `110.`

For variable `d`:

- On the first bar there is no previous value so `nz(d[1])` returns `0` and the value `0 + 10 = 10` is assigned to `d`.
- On the second bar, `nz(d[1])` returns `10` and the value `10 + 10 = 20` is assigned to `d`, and so on.
- In the case of `d`, the recently initialized value of `100.` on each bar is, in fact, never used.

Comment: Thanks for this answer @PineCoders-LucF. 
Do function calls work like instances incl. memory? If I add 2 lines to the code with a new variable `... a := f_(a)
e = 22.
e := f_(e) 
...` 
it does not change the values for `a`, even though the function is called afterwards again for `e`, so it seems to me that each function calls has his own previous values. is this correct? See changed code in this screenshot: [link](https://imgur.com/5ERGXtP) Thanks, Seb

Comment: Correct. Each function call to the same function maintains its independent history. [This usrman page](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Functions_and_annotations.html#execution-of-pine-functions-and-historical-context-inside-function-blocks) explains it. The second code snippet [here](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-examine-the-value-of-a-string-in-my-script) shows a practical advantage of using this fact. Understanding this behavior is helpful in understanding the constraints of functions, but it also unlocks interesting potential in their use.

Comment: Great, thanks again for your help and the references - I guess I am able to figure out the initial problem which I had understanding an existing script.